# Update an entire record using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I have a working code here.

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var result = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookNumber == bookNumber);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.MyColumnName= "Some new value";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But I have many properties to change. So I was trying for something like

```
            result= newResult;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

But this is not working. Is there any idea to replace a record with a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can not do this so easily.

You should create a method in your Book class, where you change all of the properties.

```cs
result.Update(Book newProperties);
db.SaveChanges();
```

or

```cs
result.Update(string prop1, int prop2, etc.);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Automapper](http://automapper.org). You can use it like this:

```
var result = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookNumber == bookNumber);
if (result != null)
{
    Mapper.Map(newResult, result);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Notice, that probably you will need to properly configure Automapper(e.g. to ignore Id properties when updating)